# python-vlc tkinter application for playing videos on linux

Tags: tkinter, python-vlc

I am using python-vlc and tkinter and am getting an error like this :

/usr/bin/python3.6 /home/user/PycharmProjects/Edtech/temp.py

```
[00007f399400e010] main filter error: Failed to create video converter
[00007f39b4092b90] vdpau_avcodec generic error: Xlib is required for VDPAU
```

The application seems to working fine and playing videos but I dont understand these errors. Can anyone please explain this ?

The application plays video selected from the computer storage

Thank you

Comment: If the code runs fine, when do you receive such an error?

Comment: Error comes up when I click on the play button.